# Is there anyway to reduce these lines?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, inheritance

I am using LeanFT for Mobile GUI Test Automation. We have 1 IOS App and 1 Android.

We have to use two different classes that are generated automaticly.
These classes contain the same method.

The methods are however not in the Base class.

Now I have to type the exact code twice while doing a cast first.

```java
abstract class Base{
    //auto generated, cannot change anything
}

class IOS extends Base{
    //auto generated, cannot change anything
    public void launch(){}
}

class Android extends Base{
    //auto generated, cannot change anything
    public void launch(){}
}

//**************
// current Code
//**************

// Custom Method:
public Base getSpecific(){
    if(//IOS){
        return new IOS();
    }
    if(//Android){
        return new Android();
    }
    return null;
}

Base base = getSpecific();

if(//IOS){
    IOS ios = (IOS)base;
    ios.launch()
    // do same stuff
} else{
    Android android = (Android)android;
    android.launch()
    //do same stuff
}
```

Now I have to type the same thing in the last if twice.
Is there a way to reduce that to only type it once?

Comment: Not unless you can modify `Base` (or both `IOS` and `Android` classes).

Comment: @Kayaman it's perfectly possible to create a class between Base and the current implementation classes

Comment: Alternatively you could introduce an interface that declares that method (e.g. `Launchable`) and cast to that to call `launch()` - if you have a way to add that to the generated code that is.

Comment: @Stultuske well then you'd need to change 2 classes that are "autogenerated, cannot change anything".

Comment: Does `// do same stuff` depend on the specific classes as well?

Comment: @Kayaman indeed, I missed that. In that case, they'll still be generated like that, even if you alter the base class

Answer (score 0):

**To reduce line of code , you can use Factory Design  Pattern**

***Please try to follow my steps here***

1. Create factory class

```
public class FactoryOperationSystem {
    public Base getOs(String osType){

          if(osType.equalsIgnoreCase("IOS")){
             return new IOS();

          } else if(osType.equalsIgnoreCase("ANDROID")){
             return new Android();

          } 

          return null;
       }
}
```

2 . Add base class same like you ,
In base abstract class , I added sample method to understand

```
public abstract class Base {

    public void osDes() { // Just Exsample Only  , you can remove it as your question 

    }
}
```

3 .Create IOS class and extend Base class

```
public class IOS extends Base{

public void osDes() {
        System.out.println("IOS");
    }
}
```

4 . Same as create Android class and extend Base class

```
public class Android  extends Base{
    public void osDes() {
        System.out.println("ANDROID");
    }
}
```

5. Create class with MainMethod to access the Factory which you want

```
public class AccessFactories {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//In here You can see How I am trying to access factory 
        FactoryOperationSystem operatingSystemFactory = new FactoryOperationSystem();

           Base base=operatingSystemFactory.getOs("IOS");
           base.osDes();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

The `getSpecific()` method already provides a concrete implementation of the `Base` class, depending on the `if` statements within that method. So the *actual* returned instance is either an `IOS` or an `Android` instance.

You don't have to cast; since both `IOS` and `Android` extend from `Base` the compiler is certain that they have a `launch` method.

```
getSpecific().launch();
// Do same stuff
```

is sufficient.